# How to create Batch file to run npm start directly?

Tags: angular, npm

I want to create a batch file to run node project directly. I want this batch file to ask me to prompt inputs to be used in the run time for my project.

Comment: that's too vague, specify the concrete case you want to automate

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: @Zafta [Link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-run-a-shell-or-batch-command-from-angular-5-or-6-or-7-application) I used this to solve my problem

Comment: @KumarGaurav You were solving this problem for past 2 years 0_0